# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reset a forms values to the initial ones:

This is the jquery being used and this is the line that is getting the error. Specifically the $("#gquestion")[0].reset();

```
    function questionhide() {
    $("#gquestion")[0].reset();
}
```

and it's called like this as I want this to happen on the hiding of the form:

```
    $("#gquestion").hide(questionhide());
```

in this file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#passwordreset").hide(passwordhide());
$("#hardwareissue").hide(hardwarehide());
$("#softwareissue").hide(softwarehide());
$("#servicerequest").hide();
$("#question").hide(questionhide());

$("#problemtype").change(function() {
    if ($("#problemtype").val() == "passwordreset") {
        $("#question").hide(questionhide());
        $("#hardwareissue").hide(hardwarehide());
        $("#softwareissue").hide(softwarehide());
        $("#servicerequest").hide();
        $("#passwordreset").show();

    } else if ($("#problemtype").val() == "hardware") {
        $("#question").hide(questionhide());
        $("#passwordreset").hide(passwordhide());
        $("#softwareissue").hide(softwarehide());
        $("#servicerequest").hide();
        $("#hardwareissue").show();

    } else if ($("#problemtype").val() == "software") {
        $("#passwordreset").hide(passwordhide());
        $("#question").hide(questionhide());
        $("#hardwareissue").hide(hardwarehide());
        $("#softwareissue").show();


    } else if ($("#problemtype").val() == "servicerequest") {
        $("#servicerequest").show();


    } else if ($("#problemtype").val() == "question") {
        $("#passwordreset").hide(passwordhide());
        $("#hardwareissue").hide(hardwarehide());
        $("#softwareissue").hide(softwarehide());
        $("#question").show();
    }

});



// Password jquery handling ---------------------------------

function passwordhide() {
    $("#system option:eq(0)").attr('selected','selected');
    $("#passwordreset")[0].reset();
    $("#otherdiv").hide();
}

$("#system").change(function() {
    if ($("#system").val() == "Other") {
        $("#otherdiv").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#otherdiv").hide(function () {
            $("#pwother").val('');
        });
    }
});


// General Question handling ---------------------------------

function questionhide() {
    $("#question")[0].trigger('reset');
}
```

and here is the entire html form that it refers to:

```
<form method="POST" action="/ticket" id="gquestion">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input name="probtype" type="hidden" value="General Question">

<div class="form-group">
    <label form="control-label">Please tell us your question:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="other" id="gqtext"></textarea>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

The form is included in this:

```
<h1 id='CaT'>Create a Ticket</h1>

<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action='/ticket' name="categoryselect">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Please select what you are having a     problem with:</label><br>
        <div class="selectContainer">
            <select class="form-control" name="problemtype" id="problemtype">
                <option disabled selected value>--Select a Category--</option>
                <option value="passwordreset">I want to reset my password</option>
                <option value="hardware">I want to report a hardware issue</option>
                <option value="software">I want to report a system/software issue</option>
                <option value="sevicerequest">I want to submit a service request</option>
                <option value="question">I have a general question</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@include('createTicket/question')
```

I have used the indexing on other forms as can be seen with the password reset in the same document, and it has worked. They have more elements in them but they do contain textarea and they have cleared properly and I haven't encountered errors. Doing

```
function questionhide() {
    $("#gtext").val('');
}
```

works but I would like to know why it won't work with the reset line I have now when other forms do. The title is the error I get when I load it up.

Comment: You are not calling the hide method correctly.  Check the jquery doc here.
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Apologies, but I fail to see how I'm calling the hide method incorrectly. I also have other forms that call it the exact same way (literally just change the id reference and the function being called) and they hide just as I want them to. If I only want to hide the form, it would just be $("#gquestion").hide();

Comment: Hide has 3 overloads.  One without any parameters,  which you are clearly not calling.
That left us with A) .hide( [duration ] [, complete ] ),   B) .hide( options )  and C) .hide( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] ).  Now lets look at the type of you questionhide().  Its a function so therefore,  you are not calling overload A and C.   That left us with overload B.  Since function is an object in Javascript,  its trying to interpret your questionhide as the options for hide().   But this is clearly not your intention. This is what I mean by your not calling it correctly.

Comment: So I changed it to $("#gquestion").hide({complete: questionhide()}) and my issue with reset is still there.

Comment: Same error message?  If so,  post complete code please.
You did close the form right?

Comment: Yes, same message. Something is leading me to think the index isn't working the way I think it does. Oh, I see I missed that when copying, yes, the form is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

```
$("#gquestion").hide(100, questionhide()); // You can change 100 to any other number. It represents the duration of the hide effect.
```

or:

```
 $("#gquestion").hide({complete: questionhide()});
```

And Change: `$("#gquestion")[0].reset();` to `$("#gquestion").trigger('reset');`

Didn't test it, but it should work.

You may also try:

```
function questionhide(){
    document.forms.namedItem("gquestion").reset();
}
```

Looks to me like your function is being created before the document loads, making `$('#gquestion')` undefined.

Comment: I have tried the second one. But my error is still in the function on the $("#gquestion")[0].reset() line.

Comment: Did you follow the second step, calling trigger instead of the reset method?

Comment: Just did so, it changes to "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined" on the cause by that line